# Is it possible to get the client process ID of an application that runs on SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, visual-foxpro

For my VFP application, i have a program to check currently who is accessing the server (by using sp_who2), also another progam to check who is currently locking which table.

But i wish to know which options my users is accessing at the moment. Am thinking if i can write a SP to get the current connected process ID for a specific client, and insert to a table(ActLog) in SQL with the program name pass into this table during users load the program. And delete that particular record when user unload the program.

Then from the ActLog, i can know who is currently accessing to which program. 
At the moment, i wish to know if i able to get the client process ID?

rgds/Andrea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`host_process_id` in [`sys.dm_exec_sessions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx):

> Process ID of the client program that
>   initiated the session

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
How to i know which records is my current connected session?

Comment: i am able to get my current connected session by executing the following: 


SELECT   session_id, login_time, login_name, host_name, host_process_id , status 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions  where session_id = @@SPID